# How do I trace the ACL2 rewriter?

Tags: acl2

How do I trace the ACL2 rewriter?  I would really like to know what's going on inside the prover.  Is it advisable to seek out this type of information or should I just follow The Method?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some relevant trace forms, authored by Matt Kaufmann:

```
(trace$ (rewrite :cond (null ancestors)
                 :entry (list 'rewrite term alist)
                 :exit (list 'rewrite (cadr values))))

(trace$ (rewrite-with-lemma
         :entry
         (list 'rewrite-with-lemma
               term
               (base-symbol (access rewrite-rule lemma :rune)))
         :exit
         (list 'rewrite-with-lemma (cadr values) (caddr values))))

(open-trace-file "my-trace-file") ; since renamed to big-trace.txt
```

Then run your proof you want trace

```
(close-trace-file)
```

Open up the trace file, my-trace-file in this example, in your favorite text editor.

With regards to your second question, 80% or more of ACL2 experts would say that, no, you don't need to know what's going on with the rewriter.  I happen to disagree with them, which is why I've written this Q&A (as I will reference it myself indirectly via Google).  You should also look into options like "break-rewrite" and "dmr".  See ACL2 documentation topic "debugging" for more information.